# How can I select the previous char from the cursor position in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textselection

I am making an combobox that changes the richTextBox's font, and I would like to be able to automatically change the combobox's selection when I click on a specific text in it, matching its font. I thought, it would be appropriate to add an onClick event on the text. This event would take the curent cursor position and make a selection with the range between the previous position and the current. I would be able to get the font from this selection.

If you know how, or can see a better way to complete this, thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to actually create a selection range, just looking at `rtb.SelectionFont.Name` will return the font name from the current caret position (i.e. without needing to select anything)

Comment: SelectionFont doesn't exists for a RichTextBox in c#. All I found is rtb.Selection.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBox.FontFamilyProperty), and it finds no value since no text is selected. The cursor is at a specific opsition, that's all. Thanks tough for the help

Comment: Ah, its there in the windowsforms one, your using WPF?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just forgot this subtility. I added a new tag.

Comment: `rtb.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty).ToString();` looks to do the same

Comment: Well, You are right. I saw this solution before, but there was an error in my code preventing this from working. Thanks for helping me realize my mistake.